# PG group by error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, group-by

Want to group my table with `created_at` date, `user_id`, `action` and `trackable_type`.

But following group by query not working for PG and giving error.

```
PG::GroupingError: ERROR: column "activities.id" must appear in the GROUP BY...

activities = Activity.all.group("activities.created_at::date, activities.user_id, activities.action, activities.trackable_type")
```

so added `activities.id` to the group by function

```
activities = Activity.all.group("activities.created_at::date, activities.user_id, activities.action, activities.trackable_type, activities.id")
```

which giving me following result for `puts "#{activities.map{|a| a.id}}"`

```
[645, 646, 642, 643, 644]
```

correct result should be

```
1 => [645, 646, 642], 2 => [643, 644]
```

Using:

ruby 1.9.3

rails 3.2.6

pg 0.14.0

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a [select](https://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.3/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/select) list to narrow the query and then you should not need to add `activities.id` to the `GROUP BY` clause.

Standard SQL requires all items in the `SELECT` clause to be either aggregated or included in the `GROUP BY` clause.  Rails by default does a `SELECT *` in ActiveRecord queries which then forces you to include all fields in the `GROUP BY`.  Limiting the `SELECT` list fields may help.

Try this:

```
activities = Activity.all
               .select(:created_at, :user_id, :action, :trackable_type)
               .group("activities.created_at::date, activities.user_id, activities.action, activities.trackable_type")
```

Comment: Strange it returns  wrong number of arguments(4 for 0) error